# Should we create fabricators for a join table model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, has-many-through, join

I have created a join table between 2 models to represent a 'many-to-many' relationship between them (with a `has_many: through` association).

I am now writing the tests and I wonder if I should create a Fabricator for that join table model ? My join table only has the foreign keys of the 2 related models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only really need factories for the models you will be creating in your tests.

For example if you have:

```
class User
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :user_projects
end

class UserProject
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, through: :user_projects
end
```

You don't really need a factory for `UserProject` as ActiveRecord creates the join models when needed.

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  projects(count: 3)
end

Fabricator(:project) do
  user
end
```

However if the "pivot" model is more than just a simple join table and has attributes on its own it is often useful to have a factory for that object:

```
class User
  has_many :lists
  has_many :tasks, through: :lists
end

class List
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task
  belongs_to :list
  has_one :user, through: :list
end

Fabricator(:list) do
  name { 'Shopping List' }
  user
  tasks(count: 3)
end
```

Comment: that makes lots of sense thanks @max. However, when you say "You don't really need a factory for UserProject as ActiveRecord creates the join models when needed.", is it also the case for ```has_many :through``` associations ?

Comment: Yes, in the first example doing either `user.projects.create` or `project.users.create` would also insert a record into `user_projects`.